# Regular Expression Java condition

Tags: java, regex

I want to make one regex with the help of java with following condition.

Their is Leave app

```
(1) CL
(2) RH
```

i want to write regex for String

```
CLCLRHRHCL
```

any combination but `RH not more than 2`

so write this

```
^([CL]* | ?> [RH]{1,4})*$
```

but RH 2 condition not working

---

hii 
     i want to add some more clear on this question

String is not fixed

CLCLRHRHCL

String may be start with RH as well

like

RHCLCLRHCL
CLRHCLRH

or any combination

but i want in all string the RH should not more than 2 i was reading java docs and other regex book but still not found solution.

my regex is :

^([CL]*|[RH]{1,4})*$

This regex : ^[CL]*|[RH]{1,4}$

working fine but when i add * for no of occurrences RH condition stop working.

Note :don't worry about  spaces and all i am not going provide any space in input.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: As I understand your question (you want a string containing any number of the string `"CL"` and at most 2 of the string `"RH"`), my answer will work perfectly. You can also just replace `{0,2}` with how many matches of `"RH"` you want (currently it is 0 to 2 matches).

Answer (score 5):

You really need to read a regex tutorial.

I'm assuming the spaces weren't just for clarity, otherwise the regex won't even compile (note the difference between the code compiling and the regex compiling), but even if it did, a similar argument as below will hold.

```
^([CL]* | ?> [RH]{1,4})*$
```

**means the following:**

- Start of string (`^`)
- Followed by zero or more of the following: (`(...)*`)

  - Either of these: (`...|...`)

    - Zero or more characters that are **either C or L** (`[CL]*`), then **a space** (`" "`) (yes spaces matter)
    - **An optional space** (`" ?"`) **followed by `"> "` followed by 1 to 4 characters that are either R or H** (`[RH]{1,4}`)
      To be an independent non-capturing group `(?>...)` **it actually needs to be in brackets**
- Followed by end of string (`$`)

**This should work:**

```
^(CL)*(RH(CL)*){0,2}$
```

**Explanation:**

- Start of string (`^`)
- Followed by zero or more `"CL"` strings (`(CL)*`)
- Followed by 0 to 2 (`{0,2}`) of the following:

  - An `"RH"` string
  - Followed by zero or more `"CL"` strings (`(CL)*`)
- Followed by end of string (`$`)

**A more understandable version:**

```
^(CL)*(RH)?(CL)*(RH)?(CL)*$
```

**Explanation:**

- Start of string (`^`)
- Followed by zero or more `"CL"` strings (`(CL)*`)
- Followed by an optional `"RH"` string (`RH?`)
- Followed by zero or more `"CL"` strings (`(CL)*`)
- Followed by an optional `"RH"` string (`RH?`)
- Followed by zero or more `"CL"` strings (`(CL)*`)
- Followed by end of string (`$`)

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: +1, but I think you've got a typo there.  The syntax for a non-capturing group is `(?:...)`, not `(?>...)`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Changed it to "independent non-capturing group".

Comment: So you're saying the OP is trying to use an atomic group, and you're just correcting his syntax?  You may be right, but with the obvious language barrier on top of everything else, this looks to me like a case of *You Can't Get Here From There*: attempting to critique the OP's solution will just cause even more confusion, so concentrate on explaining your own solution thoroughly and clearly.  That's how I roll, anyway. :D

Comment: @AlanMoore No idea whether OP even knows what an "independent non-capturing group" is, but can't explain where the `?>` would come from otherwise. Not sure if it will help, but edited. The language barrier is always a pain.